Can I connect two speakers to a mono analog input Class-D audio amplifier
I am using LM4670SD/NOPB in my design. The chip supply voltage is 5 V. My question can I connect two speakers to this amplifier as shown below. If yes what are the things to be taken care.


What's your supply voltage? What are the speakers' impedances? What's the power level you want to deliver into the speakers?

5V Supply to chip.8Ω Speaker.Power level not decided some 200mW to 500mW

The datasheet says it will work at 5V with one 4 ohm speaker, which is about the same as two 8 ohms speakers in parallel, so it should be fine.
If having two speakers results in more speaker cone surface area it will also move more air which means it will be more efficient (in dB output at 1W).
Both speakers should be wired with the same polarity.
